# Run a Java REPL on Android emulator or device

Tags: java, android, read-eval-print-loop

Would it be possible to have a Java REPL running on an Android emulator/device where you can also use Android classes for testing purposes?

Comment: JVM != (DVM  || ART) right?have you checked [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en)?

Comment: And can you put a possible scenario?Because you have .class files which you want to bridge with OAT files and then be rooted because the android sandbox will not let you access features without permissions,signatures etc etc.